# Why am I getting an InvalidParameterValueException in AWS Glacier multipart upload when I haven't exceeded the part limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

AWS S3 Glacier Multipart Upload

According to AWS, the maximum number of parts per upload for S3 Glacier multipart upload is 10,000.
I was trying to upload a zip file to the Glacier using CLI and it has been split to 53 files (52 x 1,024,000KB + 1 x 148,342KB).

When I was trying to upload the 16th file,
PS Y:\ > aws glacier upload-multipart-part --body Y:\ProjectRefDoc_230513.7z.016 --range 'bytes 17592186044416-17593234620415/*' --account-id - --vault-name XXXXXXX --upload-id XXXXXXXXXX
The powershell returns an error as below:
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UploadMultipartPart operation: This is part number 16385 for the current multipart upload. It exceeds the limit of 10000 parts.

I don't understand as I should only have uploaded 15 parts which is way below the limit of 10000 parts?

When I use the list-parts command,
PS Y:\ > aws glacier list-parts --account-id - --vault-name XXXXXXX --upload-id "XXXXXXXXXX"
The powershell did return 15 parts that I have previously uploaded:
`{
"Parts": [
{
"RangeInBytes": "0-1048575999",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "1073741824-2122317823",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "2147483648-3196059647",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "4294967296-5343543295",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "8589934592-9638510591",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "17179869184-18228445183",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "34359738368-35408314367",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "68719476736-69768052735",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "137438953472-138487529471",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "274877906944-275926482943",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "549755813888-550804389887",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "1099511627776-1100560203775",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "2199023255552-2200071831551",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "4398046511104-4399095087103",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
},
{
"RangeInBytes": "8796093022208-8797141598207",
"SHA256TreeHash": "XXX"
}
]
}'

Would be super grateful if someone could help to solve this issue, thankssssss

Comment: That number is suspiciously close to 2^14 - no idea what is going on there though.

Comment: Amazing observations @@ I think I have figured out what is going wrong... Should be due to the wrong range "bytes ..." Cuz i used Excel to generate the range and i used wrong formula generating wrong range! Lemme get back to you after i revised the range!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use "aws glacier", rather then what normally is used, glacier storage class in S3. These are not the same thing.